# Material UI Autocomplete values displaying as undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can't seem to get this to work - it's quite a simple case (I thought) with an array of options where `value` is the value, and `desc` is the label.

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

const VALUE = "email";

const options = [
  {
    value: "online",
    desc: "Online / Social Media"
  },
  {
    value: "phone",
    desc: "Telephone call"
  },
  {
    value: "email",
    desc: "Email"
  },
  {
    value: "postal",
    desc: "Arrived via postal service"
  }
];

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState("Result value here...");

  const handleChange = (e, v) => {
    setResult(v.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        id={"p_source"}
        openOnFocus={true}
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={options}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(o, v) => o.value === VALUE}
        getOptionLabel={(o) => o.desc}
        defaultValue={VALUE}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label={"Hello"} variant="outlined" />
        )}
      />
      <p>|{result}|</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

It should be displaying the current `VALUE`, in this example hardcoded as `email`, but I just get `undefined`.

I've tried things like, in the `defaultValue`:

```
{options.find((o) => o.value === VALUE)}
```

...but that's not it. What am I missing here?

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-monad-ss8wqx?file=/Demo.tsx)

Comment: just update your compare function,
  `const compare = (o, v) => {
    console.log({ o, v });
    return o.value === v.value;
  };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DefaultValue of  should have the same format as your options

change :

```
    defaultValue={VALUE}
```

with :

```
    defaultValue={options.find((option) => option.value === VALUE)}
```

you can try this

```
export default function ComboBox() {
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState("Result value here...");

  const handleChange = (
    event: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>,
    value: TOption
  ) => {
    if (value) {
      setResult(value.value);
    }
  };

  const compare = (o: TOption, v: TOption) => {
    if (v === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    console.log({ o, v });
    return o.value === v.value;
  };

  const getOptionLabel = (o) => {
    console.log({ o });
    return o.desc || "";
  };

  const getDefaultValue = React.useCallback(() => {
    return options.find((option) => option.value === VALUE);
  }, []);
  const defaultValue = React.useMemo(() => getDefaultValue(), [
    getDefaultValue
  ]);
    
  const refAutocomplete = React.useCallback(
    (node: Element) => {
      if (node) {
        setResult(defaultValue.value);
      }
    },
    [defaultValue]
  );

  // or useEffect and remove refAutocomplete 
  // React.useEffect(() => {
  //   setResult(defaultValue.value);
  // }, [defaultValue])

  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        id={"p_source"}
        ref={refAutocomplete}
        openOnFocus={true}
        isOptionEqualToValue={compare}
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label={"Hello"} variant="outlined" />
        )}
      />
      <p>|{result}|</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-waterfall-y5w6rv

[image]

another solution but at you own risk  :

```
export default function ComboBox() {
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState("Result value here...");
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('')
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<TOption>(null)

  const handleChange = (
    event: React.SyntheticEvent<Element, Event>,
    value: TOption
  ) => {
    if (value) {
      setResult(value.value);
      setSelected(value);
    }
  };

  const compare = (o: TOption, v: TOption) => {
    if (v === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    console.log({ o, v });
    return o.value === v.value;
  };

  const getOptionLabel = (o) => {
    console.log({ o });
    return o.desc || "";
  };

  const getDefaultValue = React.useCallback(() => {
    return options.find((option) => option.value === VALUE);
  }, []);
  const defaultValue = React.useMemo(() => getDefaultValue(), [
    getDefaultValue
  ]);

  const refAutocomplete = React.useCallback(
    (node: Element) => {
      if (node) {
        setResult(defaultValue.value);
        setSelected(defaultValue);
      }
    },
    [defaultValue]
  );

  // or useEffect and remove refAutocomplete
  // React.useEffect(() => {
  //   setResult(defaultValue.value);
  //   setSelected(defaultValue);
  // }, [defaultValue])

  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        id={"p_source"}
        value={selected}
        ref={refAutocomplete}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={(_, newInputValue) => {
          setInputValue(newInputValue)
        }}
        openOnFocus={true}
        isOptionEqualToValue={compare}
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label={"Hello"} variant="outlined" />
        )}
      />
      <p>|{result}|</p>
      <p>|{inputValue}|</p>
      <p>|{selected?.value}|</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-rgb-vr4vx6?file=/Demo.tsx